# Applying piecewise linear model for multiple year

Tags: r, tidyverse, piecewise

I have daily rainfall data which I have converted to yearwise cumulative value using following code

```
library(tidyverse); library(segmented); library(seas); library(SiZer)

## get mscdata from "seas" packages
data(mscdata)
dat <- (mksub(mscdata, id=1108447))
dat$julian.date <- as.numeric(format(dat$date, "%j"))

## generate cumulative sum of rain by year
df <- dat %>% group_by(year) %>% mutate(rain_cs = cumsum(rain)) %>% ungroup
```

Then I want to divide every year into 2 parts (before 210 days and after 210 days) then apply piecewise linear model from `SiZer` to identify yearwise breakpoints. I could able to do it for single year like

```
data <- subset(df, year == 1975)

sub1 <- filter(data, julian.date < 210)
sub2 <- filter(data, julian.date > 210)

sub1.mod <- piecewise.linear(x= sub1$julian.date, y = sub1$rain_cs,
                             middle = 1,
                             CI = T,
                             bootstrap.samples = 1000)
sub1.mod

sub2.mod <- piecewise.linear(x= sub2$julian.date, y = sub2$rain_cs,
                             CI = T,
                             bootstrap.samples = 1000)
sub2.mod
```

Now how to dynamically fit piecewise linear model for all the years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a function and `base R`, creating a list and then saving the models. I include in last line a way to export all models outside the list:

```
library(tidyverse); library(segmented); library(seas); library(SiZer)

## get mscdata from "seas" packages
data(mscdata)
dat <- (mksub(mscdata, id=1108447))
dat$julian.date <- as.numeric(format(dat$date, "%j"))

## generate cumulative sum of rain by year
df <- dat %>% group_by(year) %>% mutate(rain_cs = cumsum(rain)) %>% ungroup

#Create list

Listyear <- split(df,df$year)

#Function for year process
model_function<-function(x)
{
  data <- x
  
  sub1 <- filter(data, julian.date < 210)
  sub2 <- filter(data, julian.date > 210)
  
  sub1.mod <- piecewise.linear(x= sub1$julian.date, y = sub1$rain_cs,
                               middle = 1,
                               CI = T,
                               bootstrap.samples = 1000)
  sub1.mod
  
  sub2.mod <- piecewise.linear(x= sub2$julian.date, y = sub2$rain_cs,
                               CI = T,
                               bootstrap.samples = 1000)
  sub2.mod
  
  #Group elements
  list.model <- list(v1=sub1.mod,v2=sub2.mod)
  names(list.model)<-paste0(c("sub.mod1.","sub.mod2."),unique(x$year))
  return(list.model)
}
#Iterate over all models
z1 <- lapply(Listyear,model_function)
#Export elements to envir
lapply(z1,list2env,.GlobalEnv)
```

You will end up with `z1`:

```
$`1975`
$`1975`$sub.mod1.1975
[1] "Threshold alpha: 85.0000277968913"
[1] ""
[1] "Model coefficients: Beta[0], Beta[1], Beta[2]"
(Intercept)           x           w 
  26.730070    3.376754   -2.406744 
      Change.Point Initial.Slope Slope.Change Second.Slope
2.5%      82.87297      3.259395    -2.515015    0.9283611
97.5%     87.90540      3.478656    -2.273062    1.0153773

$`1975`$sub.mod2.1975
[1] "Threshold alpha: 274.000071675723"
[1] ""
[1] "Model coefficients: Beta[0], Beta[1], Beta[2]"
(Intercept)           x           w 
 -37.968273    2.150220    5.115431 
      Change.Point Initial.Slope Slope.Change Second.Slope
2.5%      272.0000      1.969573     4.750341     7.057207
97.5%     276.0001      2.371539     5.468130     7.504963
```

And by running last line you will get the models in the global environment:

[image]

I hope this can help.

**Code for exporting to csv.**

I include an additional function that takes some results from the models and creates dataframes so that it can be easily exported to `.csv` after doing some adjusts to lists. The function is next:

```
model_export<-function(x)
{
  data <- x
  
  sub1 <- filter(data, julian.date < 210)
  sub2 <- filter(data, julian.date > 210)
  
  sub1.mod <- piecewise.linear(x= sub1$julian.date, y = sub1$rain_cs,
                               middle = 1,
                               CI = T,
                               bootstrap.samples = 1000)
  sub1.mod
  
  sub2.mod <- piecewise.linear(x= sub2$julian.date, y = sub2$rain_cs,
                               CI = T,
                               bootstrap.samples = 1000)
  sub2.mod
  
  #Group elements for models
  #Model 1
  modelname <- rep('sub1.mod',2)
  year <- rep(unique(x$year),2)
  changepoint <- rep(sub1.mod$change.point,2)
  coefs <- as.data.frame(t(sub1.mod$model$coefficients))
  intervals <- as.data.frame(sub1.mod$intervals)
  intervals <- cbind(data.frame(confidence=rownames(intervals)),intervals)
  rownames(intervals)<-NULL
  #Build DF
  DF1 <- data.frame(modelname,year,changepoint,coefs,intervals)
  #Model 2
  modelname <- rep('sub2.mod',2)
  changepoint <- rep(sub2.mod$change.point,2)
  coefs <- as.data.frame(t(sub2.mod$model$coefficients))
  intervals <- as.data.frame(sub2.mod$intervals)
  intervals <- cbind(data.frame(confidence=rownames(intervals)),intervals)
  rownames(intervals)<-NULL
  #Build DF
  DF2 <- data.frame(modelname,year,changepoint,coefs,intervals)
  #Bind DFs
  DFG <- rbind(DF1,DF2)
  return(DFG)
}
```

Then you can apply:

```
#Apply new function to list
z2 <- lapply(Listyear,model_export)
#DF to export
MyDF <- do.call(rbind,z2)
#Export
write.csv(MyDF,file='Myfile.csv')
```

I have used it for two years having the results saved in `MyDF` and then exported to `.csv` file. Just as consideration if `rbind` would not work for any reason you could try `rbind.fill()` from `plyr` package.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is running fine. Now how can I write the output in .csv file?

Comment: @BappaDas I have included a new function in the solution so that you can export results. It depends on you what function you will use. Let me know if I can help you more.